# Stripe payments are not working if I load Woocommerce checkout via AJAX

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, payment, checkout

I'm trying to load Woocommerce checkout form via Ajax on a custom landing page so that it can have an instant checkout for the visitor.

I'm using the following code:

PHP function for AJAX:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getCheckoutPageContent', 'getCheckoutPageContentCallBack' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getCheckoutPageContent', 'getCheckoutPageContentCallBack' );

function getCheckoutPageContentCallBack() {
    $product_id        = absint( $_POST['product_id'] );
    $quantity          = absint( $_POST['quantity'] );
    $product_status    = get_post_status( $product_id );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

    if ( WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );
        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_items_in_cart', count( $items ) );
        wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_cart_hash', md5( json_encode( $items ) ) );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies', true );

        define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
        echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');

    }else{
        define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
        echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');
    }
    die();
}
```

Javascrip code:

```
var wp_ajax_url= myAjax.ajaxurl;
          var data = {
              action: 'getCheckoutPageContent',
              product_id: $('#land_prod_id').val(),
              quantity: 1
          };
          jQuery.post( wp_ajax_url, data, function(content) {
              jQuery("#buy_form_location").html(content);
          });
        } else{
```

All payment methods work except for Stripe where I get redirected to the actual checkout page, with the following error:  Payment processing failed. Please retry.

On the regular checkout page the payment works, but I'd like it to work on the one loaded via AJAX too.

I'm using this plugin: woocommerce.com/products/stripe

Comment: a lot of things/functions depend on `is_checkout()` check, which will only get true on the actual checkout page. indeed you'll get conflicts and you might need to bypass that `is_checkout()` check to fix some of the conflicts.

Comment: is_checkout() function returns true. But the following stripe listeners don't get applied:
checkout_place_order_stripe
checkout_place_order_stripe_alipay
checkout_place_order_stripe_bancontact
checkout_place_order_stripe_boleto
checkout_place_order_stripe_giropay
checkout_place_order_stripe_ideal
checkout_place_order_stripe_oxxo
checkout_place_order_stripe_sepa
checkout_place_order_stripe_sofort